# Redgate's SQLCompare Schema Comparison Not Removing or Adding Objects Via Command Line

Tags: database, command-line, redgate, sqlcompare

I have a saved SQLCompare project which I use to synchronize my local database with another "master" database. When I run the project via the GUI, everything works fine. However when I run it via the command line, only objects that exist on both sides get synchronized. For example, if a column is added to or removed from a table, that change *will* get propagated. But if a whole table was added or removed, that change *does not* get propagated to my local database. Is there some way to get the command line to synchronize everything? I want my local database to match the master database exactly.

I'm running version 8.1. Here's the command line I'm using:

```
SQLCompare.exe /project:SynchSchemaToLocal.scp /synch /v
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UI project, make sure you have 'green ticks' in the 'include in synchronization' column for each of the groups you want to sync'.

This will ensure that all objects in that group will be included when synchronizing.

Comment: That seems to have been my issue. However, if there are no differences at the time the project is created, the group checkboxes are not available. If the project is saved in that state, changes are made, and then the project file is executed via the command line, the differences are not synchronized. So it seems there must be at least one difference when the project file is created so the boxes can be checked. Not quite what I would expect, but I'll proceed like this for now and see if it continues to work. Thanks.

Comment: You're right, it's not the ideal implementation. If you have any suggestions on how you would like this to be better solved in the product we'd really appreciate it if you could send your suggestions to feedback at red-gate.com or simply use the Provide Feedback link in the product's Help menu. Thanks and kind regards, David Atkinson, Product Manager, Red Gate Software